# How to assert in django that F is only one time in ABCDEF

Tags: django, unit-testing

how do i assert that F appears only once in ABCDEF?

I used assertEqual but django states that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jorrit/virtualenvs/voetbabbel/voetbabbel/apps/mass_mailer/tests.py", line 61, in test_create_mailing_list
    self.assertContains(p.user.email,"@", 1, status_code=200)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 419, in assertContains
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status_code,
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'status_code'
```

and my code in the test:

```
self.assertContains(p.user.email,"@", 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Chris says, this isn't what `assertContains` is for. You can use one of the standard assertions:

```
self.assertTrue(p.user.email.count('@') == 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

`assertContains` is not for test random strings. It's for testing the response from view -- specifically that the response contains a certain bit of text. If you're not using a TestClient and testing against the response from one of your views, you can't use it.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [`assertEqual`](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual).  This is how the [Django testing docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/) test for this sort of thing.  Using `assertEqual` in this way will give you a little more feedback that `assertTrue` on failure.

```
self.assertEqual(p.user.email.count('@'), 1)
```